# nodelet run time symbol lookup error

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Getting run time error:  Error shown at bottom

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(xyz:DeltaNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet)

class definition:

```
namespace xyz
{

  class DeltaNodelet : public nodelet::Nodelet
  {
  public:
  DeltaNodelet();
```

nodelet xml file

```
<library path="lib/libxyz_nodelet">
  <class name="xyz/DeltaNodelet" type="xyz::DeltaNodelet" base_class_type="nodelet::Nodelet">
    <description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</description>
  </class>
</library>
```

CMakeLists:

```
add_executable(
  xyz_node
  src/xyz_node.cpp
)

add_library(xyz_nodelet src/xyz_nodelet.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
        xyz_node
        ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
        ${ZED_LIBRARIES}
    ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_nppi_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_npps_LIBRARY}
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}  
    )
```

output form nm -D xxxx.so  ( removed lines for less output)

```
000029a8 W _ZN12class_loader20class_loader_private14registerPluginIN15xyz172DeltaNodeletN7nodelet7NodeletEEEvRKSsS7_
0000262c W _ZN12class_loader20class_loader_private22AbstractMetaObjectBase11dummyMethodEv
         U _ZN12class_loader20class_loader_private22AbstractMetaObjectBase20addOwningClassLoaderEPNS_11ClassLoaderE

         U _ZN14console_bridge3logEPKciNS_8LogLevelES1_z
         U _ZN15xyz172DeletaNodeletC1Ev
         U _ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv
         U _ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv
00002640 W _ZNK12class_loader20class_loader_private10MetaObjectIN15xyz172DeltaNodeletN7nodelet7NodeletEE6createEv


         U _ZSt18_Rb_tree_incrementPSt18_Rb_tree_node_base
         U _ZSt29_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalancebPSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseS0_RS_
0000bedc V _ZTIN12class_loader20class_loader_private10MetaObjectIN15xyz172DeltaNodeletN7nodelet7NodeletEEE
0000bed0 V _ZTIN12class_loader20class_loader_private18AbstractMetaObjectIN7nodelet7NodeletEEE
0000bec8 V _ZTIN12class_loader20class_loader_private22AbstractMetaObjectBaseE
         U _ZTIN7nodelet7NodeletE
00002cd8 V _ZTSN12class_loader20class_loader_private10MetaObjectIN15xyz172DeltaNodeletN7nodelet7NodeletEEE
00002c88 V _ZTSN12class_loader20class_loader_private18AbstractMetaObjectIN7nodelet7NodeletEEE
00002c48 V _ZTSN12class_loader20class_loader_private22AbstractMetaObjectBaseE
         U _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
         U _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE
0000bef8 V _ZTVN12class_loader20class_loader_private10MetaObjectIN15xyz172DeltaNodeletN7nodelet7NodeletEEE
0000bee8 V _ZTVN12class_loader20class_loader_private18AbstractMetaObjectIN7nodelet7NodeletEEE
```

This is the ERROR

```
[ERROR] [1454710382.319065085]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/xyz_nodelet] of type [xyz/DeltaNodelet] even after refreshing the cache: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type DeltaNodelet as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225962/nodelet-run-time-symbol-lookup-error/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2016-02-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-05**:
Is the nodelet library linked against all of the other libraries that it needs? I would be useful for you to **edit** your question to include your CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

changed nodelet.xml to use a namespace xyz in type. That resolved this issues

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2016-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0